# conversion to DateTime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following  tags to select date first is for day,second for month and third for year

```
<select id="d" class="styledselect-day" tabindex="6">
                    <option value="">dd</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
<select id="m" class="styledselect-month" tabindex="7" >
                        <option value="">mm</option>
                        <option value="1">Jan</option>
                        <option value="2">Feb</option>
                        <option value="3">Mar</option>
                        <option value="4">Apr</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">Jun</option>
                        <option value="7">Jul</option>
                        <option value="8">Aug</option>
                        <option value="9">Sep</option>
                        <option value="10">Oct</option>
                        <option value="11">Nov</option>
                        <option value="12">Dec</option>
                    </select>

<select  id="y"  class="styledselect-year" tabindex="8">
<option value="yyyy">yyyy</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option>
                    </select>
```

And following is JS code, using which i am sending information to controller. Where i am storing these information in Session

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("AcceptPersonalInfo","Register")",
                        data: { dateDay: $("#d").val(), dateMonth: $("#m").val(), dateYear: $("#y").val() },
                        success: function () {
                            $("#contentSpan").load("/Register/ContactInfo");
                        }
                     });
```

Following is Session code

```
public void AcceptPersonalInfo(string dateDay, string dateMonth, string dateYear) //
        {
            Session["DateDay"] = dateDay;
            Session["DateMonth"] = dateMonth;
            Session["DateYear"] = dateYear;

        }
```

Then i have to store date in DateTime object to save into databse.

```
p.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateMonth"]) + Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateDay"]) + Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateYear"]));
```

But it is not converting it into datetime. "p.DOB" is of DateTime type. Pls help why conversion failed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are adding all integers thats why you are not getting.
 try below code

```
 string date = Session["DateMonth"].Tostring() + "-" + Session["DateDay"] + "-" + Session["DateYear"];
 p.DOB=Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
p.DOB=new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateYear"]),  
                   Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateMonth"]),
                   Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateDay"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are converting an `int`. You forgot to add separator:

```
p.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(
    Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateMonth"]) + "/" + 
    Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateDay"]) + "/" + 
    Convert.ToInt32(Session["DateYear"]));
```